Most efficient way to query for existing UUIDs within large tables in Oracle
Oracle 19 is used at the moment as DBMS. The problem is that there is a large table (ca. 4,700,000) entries that must be queried for existing records. So a query is quite expensive; the queried column already has an index.
The UUID is needed at least as returnValue, as I have to compare which one are existing and which one have to be created.
How to get the most performance out of this. Currently this is the statement used to accomplish the task:
select uuid from LT where uuid in(:uuidList)")

One point that is already on my mind is to reduce the amount of queries as to increase the number of UUIDs within the list as far as possible. But then this might be a problem if the list for the in operator becomes too large? What is a good size the DBMS can deal with?
Maybe there a better way to design the query than using in, e.g. a subselect?
Edit:
Forget to mention that the UUID is not the primary key of the table, there is a numerical primary key for the entity within the database the uuid is used by multiple databases and there for matching same objects that may have different ids within different DBMS.

Using a temporary table with an index on the ids and do an inner join is one feasable option I will have a look into.

Why do you even need to query that? If you use a random UUID, then the chance of collision is extremely low, so that you should handle it on insert using a unique or primary key. And if it is about checking what needs to be inserted or updated, then consider using merge. Right now, this sounds a bit like an XY problem.

Don't use the IN list for unique identifiers like this. This will create non-sharable cursors that will thrash the shared pool and add unnecessary parsing time. As MT0 says, you shouldn't be doing a query like this at all. But if you did, the best thing is to use a single value equality predicate with a bind variable and execute the query once per identifier. If that is an indexed column (with stats and on a non-partitioned table or with a global index), it should be quite fast. Just make sure you are using actual binds, not concatenating a string together to create your SQL.

I cannot use the merge operation as the primary key is different from the UUID so the record will always considered to be new because I do not know the primary unless querying.

@Matt That entirely depends on which condition(s) you define in the ON clause of the MERGE statement. If you only make it depend on the UUID, then the primary key is not involved at that point.


The UUID is needed at least as returnValue, as I have to compare which one are existing and which one have to be created.

Don't do multiple round-trips to the database by trying to find the non-existing rows and then performing a DML statement to insert. If you are going to create new rows from the non-existing data then MERGE the two data sets.
MERGE INTO your_table dst
USING (
  SELECT HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000000') AS uuid,
         'AAA' AS column1,
         1 AS column2
  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000001') AS uuid,
         'BBB' AS column1,
         2 AS column2
  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000002') AS uuid,
         'CCC' AS column1,
         3 AS column2
  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000003') AS uuid,
         'DDD' AS column1,
         4 AS column2
  FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.uuid = src.uuid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (uuid, column1, column2)
  VALUES (src.uuid, src.column1, src.column2);

fiddle
If you want to also UPDATE existing rows then you can include a WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ... clause.
If you want you can load the data into a temporary table and then MERGE from that (rather than using SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL ...).

You can create a table where you store and index the UUIDs and always query that table for UUIDS instead of your main table. So:

select uuid from LT_copy where uuid in(:uuidList)")
see which uuids were to be duplicated and replace them and try again until they are no longer duplicated
insert the uuids into LT_copy
insert the records into LT

So while the checks and writes are happening, LT is not being locked.
Make sure you do not do an in() search with too many records. Instead break it down to batches.
Create a queue for your uuid-candidate batches and evaluate it sequentially.
UUID has 2^122 possible values, so duplicates will not be that frequent.
